# How to trigger multiple changes via different p2.inf files in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a Plugin that has p2.inf file in META-INF. This single p2.inf file works when I get a RCP product via eclipse product export wizard. Now I want other p2.inf files in other Plugins.

I put a new p2.inf file in another plugin's META-INF directory. I made it available in exported product by selecting it in build.properties file...

For experimenting I put another p2.inf file near MyRCP.product file and again I selected this new p2.inf file under bin.includes section of build.properties file.

But I cannot make other p2.inf files work? How can I have multiple p2.inf files under different plugins work ?

After an export only one p2.inf file runs which copies a folder. But other p2.inf files that update the myrcp.ini via command .p2.touchpoint.eclipse.addProgramArg and ...removeProgramArg does not work. (Why only one p2.inf file works and why the same p2.inf file is executed always ?)

Comment: The p2.inf files exist under their plugin.jar files. The running p2.inf file is exported as Eclipse-BundleShape: dir ... That is the only difference. But I need to make the p2.inf files that are exported as jar, work.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1796277/#msg_1796277  this links describes how to do this...

Comment: _"I put another p2.inf file near MyRCP.product file"_ For a product `MyRCP.product` the associated p2 file must be named `MyRCP.p2.inf` instead of `p2.inf` (because there might be more than one `.product` files in that folder).